# $<$ and $>$ symbols used with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, c-star-algebras

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_positive_map) Wikipedia page, in the first property, it says $a_1$ < $a_2$, where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are elements of a C*-algebra.

The easiest way for me to think of $a_1$ and $a_2$ are as matrices. Does that statement mean that the smallest eigenvalue of $a_1$ is lesser than the smallest eigenvalue of $a_2$?

Comment: Often $A>0$ is written to mean that $A$ is positive definite and $A>B$ that $A-B$ is positive definite.

Comment: No, since $diag(0,2)$ is not less or equal to $diag(1,1)$ in $M_2(\mathbb C)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of matrices, $a_1\leq a_2$ means that $a_2-a_1$ is positive semidefinite. The symbols $>$ and $<$ are rarely used, because their meaning is confusing: when you write $a>0$, you could  mean that

- $a\geq0$ and $a\ne0$,

but it is common to reserve $a>0$ to denote that

- $a$ is positive definite.

The notion is only related to eigenvalues when $a_1,a_2$ are selfadjoint. In general, either you have a given C$^*$-algebra with its positive cone given or, as you can always do, you have your algebra represented on $B(H)$ and then $a\geq0$ means 
$$
\langle a\xi,\xi\rangle\geq0\ \ \ \text{ for all } \xi\in H.
$$

For matrices, the above is equivalent to $a=a^*$ and all the eigenvalues of $a$ non-negative.